# NoSuchMethodErrorThe getter 'value' was called on null

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to play a local video.the user choose video and play it on button press.The code [Here](https://github.com/norbertkross/krossone/blob/master/README.md).However I get this error and can't seem to get around it.

I/flutter ( 7097): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

```
I/flutter ( 7097): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building VideoChoosePost(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 7097): _VideoChoosePostState#bd944):
I/flutter ( 7097): The getter 'value' was called on null
I/flutter ( 7097): Receiver: null 
I/flutter ( 7097): Tried calling: value
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not instantiating `playercontroller` any where in your code, so it has a value of null.